# How do I step through code when debugging in VSCode?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm very new to debugging. My whole programming "career" has been limited to inserting print statements to try to figure out why things aren't working the way I want them to. Now I'm trying to step through my Python code in Visual Studio Code, but when I try to step into the debugger, it jumps straight to the first exception (which is like 50 steps in to be clear).

I saw that there are debugging configurations, but surely I don't have to learn all about those just to step through the code. And I know you can set breakpoints, but I'd like to see each step for now. Is there something I'm missing? I was using IDLE to step through my somewhat simple function prior to trying VSCode, but all of the little tweaks made that way too slow. Thanks for any help you can provide.

As best I can tell, this is the configuration I'm using by default:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Usually the default settings of the debugger are fine as long as you have a debugger extension installed. After that it's usually F10 to step over and F11 to step in.

Comment: May i know if your question is solved? please check my answer.

Comment: Molly, I'm sorry for the delay in checking your solution. Thank you for letting me know about pdb. I did get it to work without looking into it too much, but it seems like a very difficult debugger (e.g. having to individually check variable values). Embarrassingly enough, I figured out that all I need to do is add a single breakpoint and then when I start the debugger, it stops there and then I can step forward. Debugging this way (in VSCode) seems much better to me because you can see the variable values and the line of code being executed is highlighted. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @SunnyNonsense. Yes, python extension indeed has the debug feature, then i think you need a different way, my mistake, but glad to know question is resolved by yourself. Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the module [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Run `python -m pdb name.py` to start Debugging in Terminal.

> Type `n` to execute code step by step;
>
> Type `p <variable_name>` to check its value;
>
> Type `q` to stop and quit.

[image]

More information about python debugging please view the link i mentioned at start.

**[UPDATE]**

There's new release about VSCode-Python, please view [Two new debugger features: step into targets and function breakpoints](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-july-2021-release/#two-new-debugger-features-step-into-targets-and-function-breakpoints).

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments below the question, I eventually discovered adding a breakpoint to the first line of code allowed me to achieve the functionality I was looking for. Obviously, the execution stops at the break point, and then I am able to step all the way through to my exception, as desired. I'm not sure if a line 1 breakpoint is the correct way of doing this, but it's working for me.